# Ionic 6 AppState change causing duplicate subscription results

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am making a chat application using Ionic 6 and SignalR for test purposes only. I have a chat detail page, and in this page I am listening a BehaviorSubject which triggers from SignalR. Here is my working principle:

1. Sender sends a message
2. Sender triggers "CheckMessage" in SignalR
3. Receiver's SignalR gets it and triggers a BehaviorSubject which I've subscribed on chat detail page.
4. It gets the last sent message and show it on the screen.

Everything works as expected, but when I minimise the app and reopen it, after sending/receiving a new message, it shows two times at the screen. When I repeat this, this last message shows at the screen n times (n = how many times that I minimise the app).

How can I solve this issue or what am I missing here?

**signalR.cs:**

```
public async Task CheckMessage(int chatId)
{
    try
    {
        await Clients.OthersInGroup("group-" + chatId.ToString()).SendAsync("NewMessage", chatId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await _log.InsertErrorLog(ex);
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
constructor(....) {
    App.addListener("appStateChange", result => {
        if (result.isActive) {
            this.signalR.createHubConnection();
        } else {
            this.signalR.stopHubConnection();
        }
    });
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    App.removeAllListeners();
}
```

**signalR.service.ts:**

```
createHubConnection() {
    this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(this.hubUrl + 'URL?SOME_PARAMETERS', {
            accessTokenFactory: () => USER_TOKEN
        })
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build();

    this.hubConnection.start();

    this.hubConnection.on('NewMessage', id => {
        this.zone.run(() => { 
            this.v.newChatMessage$.next(id);
        });
    });
}

stopHubConnection() {
    if (this.hubConnection) {
        this.hubConnection.stop();
    }
}

async checkNewMessages(id: number) { 
    return this.hubConnection.invoke('CheckMessage', id);
}
```

**v.component.ts:**

```
newChatMessage$: Subject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(0);
```

**detail.component.ts:**

```
sub: Subscription;

ngOnInit() { 
    if (this.sub == undefined) {
        this.sub = this.v.newChatMessage$.subscribe(id => { 
            if (id > 0 && id == this.chat.id) {
                this.service.getLastMessage(id).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(msg => {
                    this.messages.push(msg);
                    this.scrollToBottom();
                });
                
                this.v.newChatMessage$.next(0);
            }
        })
    }
}

sendMessage() {
    this.service.addMessage(MESSAGE_ITEM).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(result => {
        this.messages.push(result);
        this.signalR.checkNewMessages(this.chat.id);
        this.scrollToBottom();
    });
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.sub) { this.sub.unsubscribe(); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because in ngOnInit() lifecycly of your detail.component, you get the last message every time it starts:

```
this.service.getLastMessage(id).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(msg => {
 this.messages.push(msg);
});
```

Solution: before doing `this.messages.push(msg)`, (or preferably in you `service.getLastMessage()` function) somehow check that if the last message already exists or not, and if not, then add it; something like:

```
if (!this.messages.includes(msg)) { //better check whith an id, rather than the text
  this.messages.push(msg);
}
```